# Calculate CRC32 checksum from File Reader with Go and Cloud Storage

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm uploading files to GCP Cloud Storage through an Api written in Go and it works fine(Option I). I wonder if I could calculate the checksum without storing the file in memory. I have tried the code in Option II, looping through the Reader and updating the checksum but didn't work it seems that I have to initialise the checksum value CRC32C upfront before make the first write as docs says in "ObjectAttrs": https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#Writer

I'm guessing that I can't stream and generate the CRC32 checksum at the same time. Is that right?. Doesn't Cloud Storage Go client has by default any checksum mechanism within the writer?.

(I skipped errors in code examples)

Option I:

```
...

func example(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
defer file.Close()

//create empty buffer
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

//Writer 
wc := bucket.Object(filename).NewWriter(ctx)

//calculate checksum
wc.CRC32C = crc32.Checksum(buf.Bytes(), crc32.MakeTable(crc32.Castagnoli))
wc.SendCRC32C = true

//copy buffer to bucket
_, err = io.Copy(wc, buf)

wc.Close()

...

}
```

Option II:

```
...

func example(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
defer file.Close()

var err error
table := crc32.MakeTable(crc32.Castagnoli)
wc := bucket.Object(filename).NewWriter(ctx)
checksum := crc32.Checksum([]byte(""), table)
wc.SendCRC32C = true

buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)
for {
    nr, er := file.Read(buf)
    if nr > 0 {
        checksum = crc32.Update(checksum, table, buf[:nr])
        nw, ew := wc.Write(buf[:nr])
    }

    if er != nil {
        if er == io.EOF {
            wc.CRC32C = checksum
            break
        }
        err = er
        break
    }
}

wc.Close()

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `io.Writer` wrapper - as most hashers update their hash via a `Write` method. With this method, no intermediate buffer is needed - and more importantly it frees your main logic from the task of managing the changing state of the hash.

So with a helper method, you can create a custom hasher for any `CRC32` polynomial and tie it to any destination `io.Writer`:

```
import (
    "hash"
    "hash/crc32"
    "io"
)

func NewCRCwriter(poly uint32, w io.Writer) *CRCwriter {

    return &CRCwriter{
        h: crc32.New(crc32.MakeTable(poly)),
        w: w,
    }

}

type CRCwriter struct {
    h hash.Hash32
    w io.Writer
}

func (c *CRCwriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = c.w.Write(p)  // with each write ...
    c.h.Write(p)           // ... update the hash
    return
}

func (c *CRCwriter) Sum() uint32 { return c.h.Sum32() } // final hash
```

To leverage this in your use case:

```
file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")      // io.Reader
defer file.Close()

wc := bucket.Object(filename).NewWriter(ctx) // io.Writer

crcw := NewCRCwriter(crc32.Castagnoli, wc)   // wrapped io.Writer

_, err = io.Copy(crcw, file) // content will be copied and hashed
if err != nil { /* */ }

wc.CRC32C = crcw.Sum() // final CRC32 hash
wc.SendCRC32C = true 
wc.Close()
```

Comment: it seems not working @colm.anseo , with the solution that you suggested the file is uploaded but I think is not checking the checksum. For example if you assign a random number to w.CRC32C . it will also work.  Then if you move wc.SendCRC32C = true before io.Copy you will realize that cloud storage will complain saying that doesn't match calculated CRC32C.